# bootstrap-datetime error Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I initialized my bootstrap datetimepicker as follow

```
$(function () {
    $('#BirthDate').datetimepicker();
});
```

The plugin works properly except when we try to select a year. If a year is clicked in the following image, the . `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined` exception will be thrown by google chrome and the click will be cancelled (nothing will happen, we cannot select a year).
On firefox, the error is `TypeError: ea[a(...).data(...)] is undefined`, on the same line

[image: Example image]

Full exception thrown by chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at HTMLSpanElement.fa (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:1)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)
```

The error is thrown on the line `217` of the `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` file (the file was de-minified by the google chrome dev tools)
Here is the revelant code, where the line 217 is the middle one (with the call to `.apply`)

```
 fa = function(b) 
 {
      return !a(b.currentTarget).is(".disabled") && (ea[a(b.currentTarget).data("action")].apply(l, arguments), !1)
 }
```

the files are included in this exact way in my _Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

where the jquery bundle is defined as follow

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Versions:

bootstrap-datetimepicker: 4.17.45

bootstrap: 3.37

JQuery: 3.1.1

Moment.js: 2.9.0

I looked it up online and found a few somewhat related topics, but none really had this exact problem and none of the I solutions found helped in any way.

Is this bug known ? Is there any available fix or workaround ?